# How to sum all odd numbers in range?

Tags: summation, arithmetic-progressions

How easy sum all odd numbers in range?

As instance: `25 + 27 + 29 + 31?`

Which formula I should apply?

Comment: Any thoughts?  Do you know how to sum the first $n$ odd numbers?

Comment: Use https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2107151/the-sum-of-the-first-n-odd-natural-numbers

Comment: How to sum first I know. but I need sum range, not starting from 1

Comment: Sum all odds up to $31$ and all up to $23$ and subtract

Comment: are your familiar with arithmetic progression?

Comment: See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression#Sum) about arithmetic series; you should [edit](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3286693/edit) your question to include the background (from your comment) that you know how to sum the first $n$ odd numbers but not a series not starting from $1$

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The sum of the first n odd natural numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2107151/the-sum-of-the-first-n-odd-natural-numbers)

Comment: @YaniorWeg:  in this question, unlike that question, OP is asking about sum of odd numbers $not$ starting with the first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you indicated in comments you know how to sum the first $n$ odd numbers ($n^2$):

$25+27+29+31=$

$(1+3+5+7+9+11+13+15+17+19+21+23+25+27+29+31)-$

$(1+3+5+7+9+11+13+15+17+19+21+23)=$

$ 16^2-12^2=(16+12)(16-12)=28\times4=112$

Comment: agrees with this formula for arithmetic series:  average term ($28$ in this case) times number of terms ($4$ in this case)

Comment: I need formula with N

Comment: using the approach illustrated in my answer, the sum of the odd numbers from $2M+1$ to $2N-1$ is $N^2-M^2=(N+M)(N-M)$

Comment: So, if I need sum between 25 and 31. it is, 25 27 29 31 I should do 15^2 - 13^2 ?

Comment: What is N and M?

Comment: $2M+1$ is the first term in the series and $2N-1$ is the last; in the example, $2M+1=25$ so $M=12,$ and $2N-1=31$ so $N=16$

Comment: is it included 25? Because it is 13 amount from 1 to 25

Comment: Yes, $25$ is included; the $12$ terms $1...23$ are not

Answer (score 0):

See that

$$25+27+29+31 = 25+(25+2) + (25+4) + (25 +6)$$

$$= 4(25) + 2+4+6 = 4(25) + 2(1+2+3).$$